# Where in ShoreTel database are live calls handled?

Tags: mysql, shoretel

In the shorewarecdr database, there are two tables (the `call` and `connect` tables) that I can join to get call info, such as who called, who took the call, and the time of the call, but these tables are updated ~ 30 - 45 seconds after the call has ended.

I am looking to generate a helpdesk ticket while the call is live, but am unsure where in ShoreTel that call data is when the call is live.  I am pretty sure it is there somewhere since the ShoreTel phones use a caller ID system (which would need to get the data from somewhere).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShoreTel does not have live calls in any database table. They are managed by an appliance which tracks the call activity and then after the call is done reports up the tree to it's server, who eventually writes the entry to the CDR database. To capture data on live calls you have to use the SDK and get info about the call via the ShoreTel TAPI based COM object.